# Grouping Items with constraints

Tags: algorithms

I have $n$ items $a_1, a_2, a_3 \cdots a_n$ and I want to find the least number of groups, but there is a list of constraints that $a_i$ can't be in the same group as $a_j$. Is this problem NP-Hard or is there a solution which does not Require Brute-Forcing the problem.

For Example I have $n=5$ items: $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5$. With this constraint table:

| Item $a_i$ | item $a_j$ |
| --- | --- |
| $a_2$ | $a_4$ |
| $a_4$ | $a_5$ |
| $a_2$ | $a_5$ |

This table just means $a_2$ can't be in the same group as $a_4$, $\cdots$.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring